# Как вычислить это выражение на C#?

Tags: c#

Как вычислить это выражение на C#?
Вычислить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну смотрите, я **могу написать готовый код**, **но** от этого будет мало пользы, поэтому я лучше расскажу **как его написать**.

Смотрите, **нужно просуммировать** некоторое выражение, а конкретно (a[i]-b[i])^2. Для этого нужен цикл и переменная с общей суммой (`double Sum = 0`). У цикла (`for`) есть "старт" (по условию равно `i = 1`), "конечное условие" (по условию `i <= 30`), ну и шаг, нам нужен каждый, а значит шаг = 1 (`i++`).

Теперь **на каждом шагу** нужно искать `a`, `b` и их разницу в квадрате (`double a, b`).

Что бы найти `a` нужно **проверить `i` на чётность**. Если число чётное, то это значит, что остаток от деления на 2 равен нулю. В С# есть оператор который возвращает остаток от деления `%`. Мы сделаем через `if-else` проверку на чётность `a % 2 == 0`. Если да - `a = (double)i/2`, иначе `a = i`.

По аналогии только со степенями можно найти значение `b`.

Теперь мы к переменной `Sum` прибавляем нашу "формулу": `Sum += Math.Pow((a-b), 2)`.

- *Функция `Math.Pow` возводит первое число в степень обозначенную вторым числом*

Я надеюсь понятно расписал, если что - пишите.

ОБНОВЛЕНО

Код:

```
double Sum = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++) // цикл
{
    double a, b;

    if (i % 2 == 0) // чётное
    {
        a = (double)i/2;
        b = Math.Pow(i, 3);
    }
    else // не чётное
    {
        a = i;
        b = i*i;
    }

    Sum += Math.Pow(a - b, 2);
}

Console.WriteLine(Sum);
```

Comment: Добрый день, спасибо за объяснение! Но можете помочь написать код? Поскольку я начал и сразу запутался

Comment: @Никита добавил код